# LibGDX Array of a Superclass

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, superclass

In my Game World class I wish to have an array of all of my enemies that are using a super class called Fighters.

```
public Array<Fighters> enemies;
```

I initialize it in the constructor of my Game World.

```
enemies = new Array<Fighters>();
```

This is the Fighters Super class.

```
public class Fighters {
     protected Vector3 position;
     protected Vector3 velocity;
     protected Texture texture;

     public Vector3 getPos() {
          return position;
     }
     public Vector3 getVelocity() {
          return velocity;
     }

     public Texture getTexture() {
          return texture;
     }
     public void setPos(Vector3 newPos) {
          position = newPos;
     }
}
```

And a class that is a subclass of Fighters.

```
public class RedFighter extends Fighters {
    public static final int value = 1;

    public RedFighter() {
        position = new Vector3(-10, -10, 0);
        velocity = new Vector3(0, -10, 0);
        texture = new Texture("redfighter.png");
    }
}
```

When I call a method called spawn enemies, it should be filling the array with redfighters. However, I keep getting a NullPointException when I try to add it.

```
Fighters fighter;
fighter = new RedFighter();
enemies.add(fighter);
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: where is your Fighters constructor and where are you assigning its class variables?

Comment: I don't want to actually make an object of Fighters so I didn't include a constructor. It was originally an abstract class but in my attempt to fix the problem I removed it.

Comment: If you get an NPE when you call `enemies.add(fighter);`, it's because `enemies` is still null. Also, not a good idea to load a texture in your RedFighter class, or the game will have to load the same texture multiple times for no reason.

Comment: Ah... you are totally right about holding not holding the texture. I'll fix that.

Comment: Could you please show the stacktrace? Also, where do you get that Array class from?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

Turns out that I didn't really have a constructor for my game world. Instead of using public GameWorld() as my declaration, I was using public void GameWorld() and so it didn't know it was my constructor. I realize that I should have posted the whole class. Thanks so much everyone! I'll make sure to post everything relevant next time.

As for where Array comes from, it's an array from the libgdx library.